# Capture Activated event for an App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#app_activation

```
    // App is an Application
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Doesn't compile
        //this.Activated += OnActivated;

        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnActivated");
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

Note, `OnActivated` will never be triggered. `OnSuspending` will be triggered, after I quit the app around 30 seconds.

How can I capture `Activated` event? It is weird that I do not find `Activated` event in `App`, although the documentation says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activation is a little confusing. Take a look at the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242324.aspx

What you'll find is that when the user taps the tile, only the OnLaunched event is fired (see documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx )

The OnActivated is only for special cases outside of the ordinary launch. That would be any one of the following:

OnFileActivated 
OnSearchActivated 
OnShareTargetActivated 
OnFileOpenPickerActivated 
OnFileSavePickerActivated 
OnCachedFileUpdaterActivated

So if you truly want something that is called anytime the app is activated regardless of how, I'd suggest making your own private method, then calling it from both OnLaunched and OnActivated. That should hit all cases for activation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you launch the app normally for example, by tapping the app tile(without facts, I'm just guessing). In this case, only the OnLaunched method is called.

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated)